# Update profile using angular native and firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a problem wherein when updating the credentials of the user, the changes doesn't reflect on the specific page. According to its docs, `updateProfile` should return a `reloadUser`, which is already in my code. Is there a missing step or code here?

```
  editProfile(displayName, contactNumber, uid) {
    firebase
      .updateProfile({
        displayName: displayName
      })
      .then(
        function() {
          return firestore
            .collection("users")
            .doc(uid)
            .set(
              {
                displayName: displayName,
                contactNumber: contactNumber
              },
              { merge: true }
            );
        },
        function(errorMessage) {
          console.log(errorMessage);
        }
      );
    firebase.reloadUser().then(
      function() {
        firebase
          .getCurrentUser()
          .then(user => console.log("User uid: " + user.uid))
          .catch(error => console.log("Trouble in paradise: " + error));
      },
      function(errorMessage) {
        console.log(errorMessage);
      }
    );
  }
```

Please help me how can the component reload itself to display all the changes in Angular Native. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The call to `updateProfile` is an asynchronous operation, because it takes time to complete. Once the update completes, the `then` is called, but by that time you've already called `reloadUser`.

I recommend running this in a debugger, and adding some logging. You'll see that your call to `reloadUser` starts before the `then()` of `updateProfile()` ever runs, which explains why you're not getting the updated profile.

The solution for this sort of problem is always the same: any code that needs the result of the asynchronous operation has to be *inside* the `then` callback that runs when that operation completes.

So:

```
firebase
  .updateProfile({
    displayName: displayName
  })
  .then(
    function() {
      firebase.reloadUser().then(
        function() {
          firebase
            .getCurrentUser()
            .then(user => console.log("User uid: " + user.uid))
            .catch(error => console.log("Trouble in paradise: " + error));
        },
        function(errorMessage) {
          console.log(errorMessage);
        }
      );
      return firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(uid)
        .set(
          {
            displayName: displayName,
            contactNumber: contactNumber
          },
          { merge: true }
        );
    },
    function(errorMessage) {
      console.log(errorMessage);
    }
  );
```

---

These days it's common to [use `async` and `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to make this code a bit easier to read. With `async`/`await` and other modern JavaScript, the above becomes:

```
await firebase
  .updateProfile({
    displayName: displayName
  });
await firebase.reloadUser();
let user = await firebase.getCurrentUser()
console.log("User uid: " + user.uid);
return firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(uid)
        .set(
          {
            displayName: displayName,
            contactNumber: contactNumber
          },
          { merge: true }
        );
```

Comment: It still displays the applied changes but you need to navigate first to other pages or simply restarting the application itself for it to display.